Briggs-Rauscher Reaction potential
I have seen many graphs on the oscillation reaction of the Briggs-Rauscher reaction. They all have potential in V or mV in the y-axis. My question is what this tells about the rate of reaction of the Briggs-Rauscher reaction. Can the oscillation period, which is dependent on temperature, explain how the rate of reaction varies with time using Arrhenius' law and rate constants?
